# Detecting PO box with Regex missing one match

Tags: php, regex

This is my current expression for detecting a PO Box as an address:

```
^\s*((P(OST)?.?\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\s+(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))
```

It matches everything I need it to except `POBox` and `P.O.Box` (where there is no space before the B). How can I adjust my expression to include that?

Link to test: https://regex101.com/r/vKDiWW/1

Comment: What are the strings your want to match? Because this regex could never be correct. (captering 9 groups, `POST.   OFFICE.    BIN` & `P  OFF.  ` are valid, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> where there is no space before the B

Right, your expression contains `\s+` and this pattern requires one or more whitespaces.

Use `\s*` or `[[:space:]]*`:

```
^\s*((P(OST)?.?\s*(O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\s*(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Idru9C/3)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to presume that you meant to match literal dots and not match any non-newline character -- so now you will see the dots in the pattern are escaped.

I moved the dots in the pattern to appreciate your required logic and I have also removed some unneeded parentheses.  See my inline comments for explanations.

Pattern:

```
~^\s*(P(\.|OST)?\s*(O(\.|FF(ICE)?)?)?\s*(B(IN|OX))?|B(IN|OX))~i
```

Regex ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKDiWW/2))

```
^
\s*
(
  P(\.|OST)?              #P or P. or POST
  \s*
  (O(\.|FF(ICE)?)?)?      #nothing or O or O. or OFF or OFFICE
  \s*
  (B(IN|OX))?             #nothing or BIN or BOX
  |
  B(IN|OX)
)
```

Disregarding all optional spaces and case-insensitivity, the above pattern will make the 45 following matches:

```
BIN
BOX
P
PBIN
PBOX
PO
POBIN
POBOX
PO.
PO.BIN
PO.BOX
POFF
POFFBIN
POFFBOX
POFFICE
POFFICEBIN
POFFICEBOX
P.
P.O
P.OBIN
P.OBOX
P.O.
P.O.BIN
P.O.BOX
P.OFF
P.OFFBIN
P.OFFBOX
P.OFFICE
P.OFFICEBIN
P.OFFICEBOX
POST
POSTBIN
POSTBOX
POSTO
POSTOBIN
POSTOBOX
POSTO.
POSTO.BIN
POSTO.BOX
POSTOFF
POSTOFFBIN
POSTOFFBOX
POSTOFFICE
POSTOFFICEBIN
POSTOFFICEBOX
```